# PHP searching trought accounts

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I want to make an admin-based account search, but I don't know on what layout shall I go.

My ideea:  Create an index page with an search bar,  type account name, generate an "ghost" .php  page with user's name.    ex: domain.com/user.php

And at that user.php  it will echo  $user's data's.

How it sounds? What I've done right now

```php
<body>
   <script>
      var button = document.getElementById("btnSearch");

      button.onclick = function () {
          var text = document.getElementById("textBoxEl").value;
          window.open("http://monkey=" + text + "&red");
      }
   </script>
   <div class="test">
   <h1 id="title-1">Search an account<em><span></span> </h1>
   <center>
      <?php
         if(isset($_POST['number'])){
             header('Location: http://localhost/ucpba/public_Html/ucp/users/'.$_POST['number']);
             exit;
         }
         ?>
      <form>
         <input type="text" id="number" name="number" />
         <input type="submit" onclick="window.location = window.location  + number.value; return false;"/>
      </form>
   </center>
   <?php }
      else header('location: index.php'); //if user isn't loged in it will redirect him on login.php
      ?>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.matchHeight-min.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/animsition.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/jquery.parallax-scroll.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/jquery.cbpQTRotator.min.js"></script> 
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#owl-partners").owlCarousel({
            autoPlay: 4000, 
            stopOnHover : true,
            pagination : false,
            items : 5,
            itemsDesktop : [1199,4],
            itemsDesktopSmall : [959,3]     
        });     
      });
   </script> 
   <script>
      $( function() {
      $( '#cbp-qtrotator' ).cbpQTRotator();                 
      });
   </script> 
   <script src="js/functions.js"></script> 
   <script src="js/particle.js"></script> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var _gaq = _gaq || [];
      _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'XX-XXXXXXXX-X']);
      _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
      (function() {
        var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
        ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
      })();
      <?php } ?>
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But I don't know how to proceed next, to create users pages.

Comment: Some points - `http://monkey=" + text + "&red` ??? what is that - it is not a valid url. An element with id `textBoxEl` does not appear in the code above. `<h1 id="title-1">Search an account<em><span></span> </h1>` unclosed `<em>` tag. Using `header` once you have output html content will cause errors ( caveat: output buffering )

Comment: Off topic, but I should point out that the `<center>` tag has been deprecated in HTML and is considered bad practice. You should find an alternative way of centring you content.

Comment: Also, watch out for potential injection attacks on your `$_POST` variables; you should be careful not to output them without validating them and escaping them. For example, what happens to your redirect if `$_POST['number']` contains something other than a number?

Comment: sounds like you need to study databases, cus this project needs a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many things to consider (Learn).
but for start,

1- you need to grab url parameter(s) with $_GET method.

2- use switch function to identify the variables.

3- inside the switch, separate cases (account_name, number)

4- query your database to get information of the users by account_name or number.

and finally display it in the page.

For changing the url, mostly you need to work with .htaccess configuration.

some useful tutorial to start:

Url rewriting: https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners

GET/POST Methods: https://www.formget.com/php-post-get/

Search: https://owlcation.com/stem/Simple-search-PHP-MySQL